# Configure message routing for Azure IoT Hub programmatically

Tags: c#, node.js, azure, azureservicebus, azure-iot-hub

We can create custom message routing on Azure IoT hub using Azure portal and Azure CLI. 
We can route message to custom endpoint (like, servicebus, eventhub etc..) based on its system properties, application properties or message body.
**Is there any way, we can configure custom message route on Azure IoT-Hub programmatically using C# or Node?** 
I mean, dynamically/programmatically we can define that telemetry message having 'xyz' key should route to specific Service bus.

Comment: Have you checked the SDKs and HTTP API reference? What steps have you taken to research your question?

Comment: IoTHub routing only works based on SQL like query https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-routing-query-syntax . For your scenario of custom code, you have to host a routing service (e.g. Azure Function or some continuous job) yourself to fan out.

Comment: Azure IoTHub routing allows to forward (publish) a message to the *Azure Event Grid* (AEG) and distribute it to the subscribers using the Fan-Out Pattern in the loosely decoupled manner based on their subscriptions. The AEG subscription can be changed (such as advanced filtering, event handlers,  etc.) on the fly using the REST APIs, for instance. Note, that the AEG doesn't guarantee distributing the messages in the order.